# Formatting eclipse project to android studio (Not just building gradle)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to re-format my eclipse project structure to android studio's. Because they dont have this feature, i will have to do this manually.

The quick question :

Anyone has a tutorial/guide to do this? I cant find any.

My specific problem now :

1. I dont know where to put my eclipse's based `bin` and `gen` folder.
2. Theres an `androidTest` folder in the android studio's based `src` folder, which have a `ApplicationTest.java` file in the end. Should i put this manually?

Im quite confuse right now. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont know where to put my eclipse's based bin and gen folder.

Delete them entirely. Android Studio and Gradle for Android will create a `build/` folder that will contain compiler outputs and intermediate code.

> Theres an androidTest folder in the android studio's based src folder, which have a ApplicationTest.java file in the end. Should i put this manually?

Only if you have a JUnit test suite. With Eclipse, that was a separate test project; in Android Studio and Gradle for Android, your test code just goes in an `androidTest` sourceset. If you have a test project, move its Java code into `androidTest/java/`; if you do not have a test project, you can leave `androidTest` alone for now.

Comment: Thanks! im trying now

Comment: Just a quick question, do you think android studio is mature enough to replace eclipse? I will have a quite complex project and i still confuse whether i use android studio or just stick with eclipse :D

Comment: @BlazeTama: Google has given some fairly strong indications that their interest in Eclipse is waning. Whether Android Studio is ready or not seems to be of secondary concern. I have not run into problems with Android Studio other than some missing capabilities found in ADT. However, my use of it has been for fairly tiny projects (book examples, mostly). *Eventually*, you will want to move to Android Studio. Whether that is now or sometime after it moves out of beta is really up to you, and probably depends on where you are in the project as much as anything else.